# Maximum product of 3 numbers in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I came across this question in a recent interview.
Given an array find the maximum product that can be obtained multiplying any 3 numbers in the array.
The solution I came up with is,

```
Sort the array
Multiply the 3 largest number.
```

This is `O(nlogn)`

Is there a `O(n)` solution to the problem?

Comment: You could sort the array in descending order, then multiply `arr[0]*arr[1]*arr[2]`

Comment: Maybe you didn't read my question.

Comment: Lol, I realized right after I wrote that comment that you said that.

Comment: @Clockwork EDIT: nvm it is O(n), There isn't any need to sort the array, just find the three biggest and store the value, then multiply them together.

Comment: Is the input non-negative?

Comment: @harold that throws a bit more complexity into it if it is... Should still be O(n) though I believe

Comment: @MitchWeaver yes not so bad, just also keep the two most negative numbers and compare two candidate products in the end

Comment: Note that the largest product might be the largest 2 *negative* numbers multiplied by the largest positive number

Answer (score 7):

Instead of sorting all the values, you can retain the top three, which is `O(3n)` which is `O(n)`

Doing this in a single pass is likely to be more efficient than three passes.

One way of doing this is to do an insertion sort into an array of 3, discarding the lowest value each time. (you can start at the lowest value in the array)

You can also implement this using a series of if/else comparison to update 3 variables.

> How about negatives?

The only complication is if you can have negative values e.g. `5 * -4 * -4 > 5 * 5 * 3`

For this reason it would makes sense to search for the three largest and the two most negative.  You can check whether the `largest * the next two largest` or `largest * the two most negative is bigger`.

> what if they are all negative?

In this case, you also need the three smallest negative values as well to get the product closest to positive infinity.

Comment: The solution taking into account negative numbers would be opportune

Comment: How about negatives.

Comment: @Clockwork See the last paragraph on how to handle negatives.

Comment: what if they are all negative?

Comment: @גלעדברקן You are right this is a different case, and you need keep the three non-positive values closest to zero. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in O(n) as follows:

- Find the largest number in O(n); remove the number from the array (make it zero)
- Find the largest number among the remaining numbers in O(n); make it zero as well
- Find the largest number among the remaining numbers, again in O(n)

You repeat the same O(n) loop three times, so it's O(3*n), which is the same as O(n) because constants are ignored.

> This won't cater to negatives

It is relatively easy to modify this algorithm to work with negative numbers. Each pass through the array needs to find the largest and the smallest negative value, so at the end you would have three large positive numbers P<sub>0</sub>, P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub> and thee large negative numbers N<sub>0</sub>, N<sub>1</sub>, N<sub>2</sub>, in ascending order by magnitude. Now you need to compare P<sub>0</sub>*P<sub>1</sub>*P<sub>2</sub> vs. N<sub>1</sub>*N<sub>2</sub>*P<sub>2</sub>, and pick the larger one.

Comment: You could do it single pass, but this is simple. +1

Comment: This won't cater to negatives.

Comment: @Clockwork Your sort-and-take-three-largest-values solution wouldn't either. Fortunately, it is easy to modify both solutions to accommodate negative values (see the edit).

Answer (score 0):

There are O(n)-time complexity solutions to this problem, but these will only occur depending on the input of your array, as you can read [in this article](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18536/what-is-a-the-fastest-sorting-algorithm-for-an-array-of-integers)

Comment: It is better to include your answer here than link to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this in 1 pass by storing largest elements from array A to to array of 3 say B.

For each element n in array A if n is greater than any element in array B then replace array B element with array A element.

Finally multiply the 3 elements in resulting array. This is constant time. This may still be 3n since you are checking against array of 3 as well.

For negative it would be additional 2 elements which contain the smallest. So it may be 5n but still constant time

Comment: How bout negative numbers.

Comment: Check bottom paragraph. You would take the highest positive and multiply by 2 lowest negatives and cross check against product of 3 positives