# Max product of 3 integers in an array

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, initialization

I am trying to solve a problem where I want to find the max product of any 3 integers in an array.

I tried my solution:

```
def maximumProduct(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """

    list_of_ints = nums

    t = sorted(list_of_ints[:4])

    max_pos = t[2] 
    max_pos_2 = t[1]
    max_pos_3 = t[0]

    min_neg = 0
    min_neg_2 = 0

    for x in list_of_ints[3:]:
        if x<0 and x< min_neg:
            temp = min_neg
            min_neg = x
            min_neg_2 = temp

        elif x<0 and x<min_neg_2: 
            min_neg_2 = x

        if x>0 and x>max_pos:
            temp = max_pos
            max_pos = x
            temp2 = max_pos_2
            max_pos_2 = temp
            max_pos_3 = temp2

        elif x>0 and x>max_pos_2:
            temp = max_pos_2
            max_pos_2 = x
            max_pos_3 = temp

        elif x>0 and x>max_pos_3:
            max_pos_3 = x

    return max(max_pos*max_pos_2*max_pos_3, min_neg*min_neg_2*max_pos)
```

The above solution fails on input `nums = [-1, -2, -3]`. The expected output is `-6`, the output of the program is `0`.

This is due to the initialization of `min_neg` and `min_neg_1` to zero.

How to initialize to avoid this issue? I always have trouble setting up the right initializations.

Comment: please give a sample of input and desired output

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105279/maximum-product-of-3-numbers-in-an-array

Comment: I think it would not hurt to clarify the approach and state that this is attempt at an O(N) solution, it's easy to miss that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Approach

To solve this kind of exercise efficiently, you need to recognize that there are only a few possible cases. Focus on the signs of the numbers and think what would be the sign of the result:

```
+ * + * + = +  (good)
+ * + * - = -  (bad)
+ * - * - = +  (good)
- * - * - = -  (bad)
anything * 0 = 0 (neutral)
```

So, if the list has both negative and negative numbers, the answer is either the product of the three largest numbers, or the product the two smallest (negative) numbers and the largest number (positive).

If this condition is not true, the answer must be the product of the largest numbers in the array.

## O(n log (n)) solution

So, the answer has to take either the three last elements in the array after sorting, or the two first ones and the last one, and multiply them together. The simplest and most elegant way to do it is to first sort the list of numbers:

```
def maximum_product(nums): # O(n log(n)) solution
   nums.sort()
   assert len(nums) >= 3 # assume the input has been validated
   a1 = nums[-1] * nums[-2] * nums[-3]
   a2 = nums[0] * nums[1] * nums[-1]
   return max(a1, a2)
```

## O(n) solution

However, you can also find the maximal three and the minimal two numbers in O(n) time. One efficient approach how to find the maximum `N` numbers in a container is to keep a heap of size `N` while iterating through it. At the end, the heap contains the answer: a partially sorted list of `N` largest elements.

Python module `heapq` offers [convenient API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) for this: the functions `nlargest()` and `nsmallest()`. So here we go:

```
import heapq

def maximum_product(nums): # O(n) solution
   assert len(nums) >= 3 # assume the input has been validated
   max3 = heapq.nlargest(3, nums)
   min2 = heapq.nsmallest(2, nums)
   a1 = max3[0] * max3[1] * max3[2]
   a2 = min2[0] * min2[1] * max(max3)
   return max(a1, a2)
```

Comment: hey your answer was really helpful;
is there a way to calculate below testcases with one function;
testcase1: nums = [-10, -5, 1, 2, 3, 4], n = 3
testcase2: nums = [-10, -5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10], n = 4

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize to negative infinity: `min_neg = float('-inf')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to make doing it very easy. What you're calling an "array" is referred to as a "list" in Python, by-the-way.

```
from itertools import combinations

def maximum_product(nums):
    return max(trio[0] * trio[1] * trio[2] for trio in combinations(nums, 3))

nums = [-1, -2, -3, 9]
print(maximum_product(nums))  # -> 54
```

This could be generalized to determine the maximum product of *N* integers by (also) using `functools.reduce()` to compute the product of *N* items:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import combinations

def maximum_product(nums, group_size):
    return max(reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, nums, 1)
                    for group in combinations(nums, group_size))

nums = [-1, -2, -3, 9]
print(maximum_product(nums, 3))  # -> 54
```

Of course, this generality will slow execution down a bit...

Comment: The time complexity of this is terrible, though: O(n^3) rather than O(n log(n)).

Comment: @kfx: How did you come up with that time complexity value?

Comment: Doesn't it go through all combinations of three elements to compute this? I'm not sure how it could be otherwise?

Comment: @kfx: It's unclear to me how one could avoid trying all combinations of 3 items in the "array" in order to determine the max product of combinations of 3 of them. What makes you think that could be avoided?

Comment: I think there are only a few possible cases:  for example, if all numbers are positive or all negative, the answer is the product of 3 largest positive numbers.

Comment: @kfx: I suppose if you could make some assumptions and hardcode things so it would not work in the general case. Regardless, I think your time complexity analysis is incorrect.

Comment: Looking back, yes I'm wrong, the author's solution is O(n), that why his code is so complex. Do'h. Not sure if this helps you :)

Comment: @kfx: Trying to speed things up by writing out code like the OP has done often backfires in Python and makes things slower than they would be if the operation was done using the built-in functions it has which are often written in C. The only true test is do some realistic  timing benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr = sorted(list_of_ints)

def getMax(t):

    maxP = t[0] * t[1] * t[2]

    i = 0
    while t[i] > -1:
        i += 1

    maxN = t[i] * t[i + 1] * t[0]

    return max(maxP, maxN)

print(getMax(arr))
```

Comment: this is nlogn complexity...my solution is o of n

Answer (score 0):

I tried kfx's O(n) solution but it was not taking into account possible negative ints for me. I added a few lines to adjust for that, and also two more possible combinations and it worked. Correct me if I am wrong but I think this is still O(n) notation right?

```
def maximum_product(nums): 
    max3 = heapq.nlargest(3, nums)
    min3 = heapq.nsmallest(3, nums)
    a1 = max3[0] * max3[1] * max3[2]
    a2 = min3[0] * min3[1] * min3[2]
    a3 = min3[0] * max3[0] * max3[1]
    a4 = min3[0] * min3[1] * max3[0]
    if abs(min(a1, a2, a3, a4)) > abs(max(a1, a2, a3, a4)):
        return min(a1, a2, a3, a4)
    else:
        return max(a1, a2, a3, a4)
```

Comment: *[kfx's O(n) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49086978/3789665) [was] not taking into account possible negative ints for me* How did this manifest? When is `a3` max, when `a2` max/`min3[2]` needed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why would you want to divide a2/min3[2] ?  a3 could be max if min3[0] is the largest absolute number and the next largest is max3[1], followed by max3[0].

Comment: A misunderstanding indeed: there is one condition before the slash (which is used in place of *respectively*) and one after. The way a1/2/3 are computed, they coincide; it may be useful to ponder each on its own.